# custom taxonomies are not showing up in get_taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I've made several taxonomies through the custom post type ui manager but i am not able to call them with get_taxonomies and my get_terms is not working either. Is there something I have to do after creating a custom taxonomy in order to get it fully functional?

$tax = get_taxonomies();
var_dump($tax);

returns only the build-in taxonomies and none of my custom ones.

Comment: Can you post your taxonomy registration settings?

Comment: they are registered automatically through the custom post type plugin

Comment: can you post the code you tried with get_taxonomies or get_terms?

Comment: The plugin should give you some options before/after registering them. Make sure they are public available so that you can run queries on them.

Comment: advanced custom fields plugin doesn't seem to offer any options for making a custom taxonomy public. does anyone know about how I would do this?

Comment: maybe try registering a simple custom taxonomy in functions.php to see if there is a problem with the plugin? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

EDIT: can you post a screenshot of the UI page from the plugin?

Comment: What said the plugin support?